# Change the order of servers in "Connect to Server" window?

Tags: macos, network, finder, sharing

Running Mavericks (OS X 10.9.4) is it possible to change the order that the "favorite servers" are displayed in?

Allow me to explain a little more the use case. In Finder if one presses Command-K or uses the "Go" menu to "Connect to Server..." a dialog box appears. In the top portion of the dialog is the current server you are about to connect to and below it the servers you have indicated are your favorites. These favorites are set by clicking the + button to the right of server line at the top. After clicking the plus button, servers are added to the top of the favorite. This results in the most recent addition being at the top.

The server I want at the top of my favorites list is the one I am accessing most often, not the one that was just added. Ideally I would like to be able to place them in order as things change.

To illustrate further, right now my list looks like this:

- Server 3
- Server 7
- Server 5
- Server 1
- Server 2
- Server 4
- Server 6

I would like to make it look like this:

- Server 1
- Server 2
- Server 3
- Server 4
- Server 5
- Server 6
- Server 7

Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I frequently fill in user's shares from the mapped drives of their old PCs and I've found that I just have to enter them in in reverse.  The first one you enter ends up at the bottom and the least you enter ends up at the top.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/469900/where-are-the-connect-to-server-settings-stored-in-mac-os-x

Comment: In Catalina, servers that have spaces anywhere in the server path are not sortable by dragging. However, those that don't have any spaces ARE sortable by dragging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

Open this file in XCode: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`

Look inside the favoriteservers container.  Drag the servers into your desired order.

[image: XCode .plist edit interface]

Save the file.

Log out.

Log in.

Done.

Also!  It sure looks like you have a separate value for Name and URL there!  I haven't tried it but it certainly would be handy to have the list display human-readable values instead of stuff like `afp://10.8.8.67`

Comment: You can put in readable names by editing your hosts file. The names will show in the Shared portion of Finder, as well as being able to ping them and save them as your favorites.

Answer (score 0):

The list is stored as an array in a dictionary named **favoriteservers** inside the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` file.  You should be able to modify the array with a plist editor, so that they display in your preferred order.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of MacOS 10.13 High Sierra, there is no `favoriteservers` in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` anymore.

Under current MacOS, it is stored as `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteServers.sfl`

Now we only need to fighe out how to modify that sfl beast.

See also:

- [Where are the “Connect to Server” settings stored in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/469900/where-are-the-connect-to-server-settings-stored-in-mac-os-x)
- [List Server Favorites in OS X 10.11 El Capitan](https://ryanmo.co/2015/10/31/list-server-favorites-in-os-x-1011-el-capitan/)

Answer (score 0):

In High Sierra you find the file in the path indicated by maosmurf.

I've edited this file with Xmplify app (payment application but cheaper one). A simple xml editor.

Maybe you can move all lines of every server and reorder this list. But I'm afraid to modify this files in my work machine and I don't know if it can be dangerous.

Make backup and try if you want.

[image]

Comment: In this image you can see all lines of one server... if you decide to move one server you must move all lines...

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to High Sierra, my favorite servers list somehow got rearranged.  But I found an easy way to move any one server from the list to the top:  After opening the "Connect to Server..." dialog box, select the entry you want on the top.  It gets copied into the top "Server Address" field.  Instead of clicking on "Connect", click on the "+" as if to add it to the favorites list.  This moves the entry to the top.  Repeat until the list is in the desired order.  That's it.
I realize the original question is pretty old, but maybe someone else is still searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS Mojave, I have had inconsistent success with simply clicking on some of the entries in the list and dragging them. I'm not sure the rhyme or reason why some of them are draggable and others are not.